# Sources of online broadband RF energy data stream?

Tags: rf, communication, signal-processing, data, signal-integrity

I am interested in finding recordings of broadband FM radio emissions, ideally in the marine VHF frequencies (156.0 and 162.025), in order to understand carrier artifacts and distortions that could affect communications. I need the raw broadband data (from an SDR), not the demodulated audio. Are there any archives of such data or live data streams?

Comment: What exactly are *"carrier artifacts and distortions"*? And why can't you just put up an antenna and capture your own live stream?

Comment: @DaveTweed I can do that, but I am somewhat inland so it would some time and nuisance to capture the data, so I am hoping there is some data online already.

Comment: Well then, you have manoeuvred yourself into the unfortunate position of having to take a trip to the beach...